# Looping through folders and renaming all files in each folder sequentially with folder name

Tags: macos, for-loop, terminal, renaming

I have a series of subfolders, each with images on them.

Structure looks like

```
/stuff/
   IMG_012.JPG
   IMG_013.JPG
   IMG_014.JPG

/morestuff/
   IMG_022.JPG
   IMG_023.JPG
   IMG_024.JPG
```

I would like to write a script on my mac terminal to loop through each folder and rename the images sequentially including the folder name.  So, the above structure would look like:

```
/stuff/
   stuff_1.JPG
   stuff_2.JPG
   stuff_3.JPG

/morestuff/
   morestuff_1.JPG
   morestuff_1.JPG
   morestuff_1.JPG
```

I orignally tried creating a Automator workflow and using variables, but had difficulty assigning the folder name as the variable and getting the loop to work.

I'm hoping there is an elegant solution with the terminal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at http://superuser.com/q/498191/328167

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work nicely for you. Save it in your HOME directory as "RenameImages", then make it executable like this:

```
cd
chmod +x RenameImages
```

Then you can run it (`-exec`) it on every directory (`-type d`) like this:

```
find . -type d -exec ./RenameImages {} \;
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Ignore case, i.e. process *.JPG and *.jpg
shopt -s nocaseglob
shopt -s nullglob

# Go to where the user says
echo Processing directory $1
cd "$1" || exit 1

# Get last part of directory name
here=$(pwd)
dir=${here/*\//}
i=1
for image in *.JPG 
do
   echo mv "$image" "${dir}${i}.jpg"
   ((i++))
done
```

At the moment it does nothing except show you what it would do. If you like what it is doing, simply remove the word `echo` from the 3rd to last line and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to throw out another way to do this since you mentioned you tried using Automator. This file search and process software: http://www.softpedia.com/get/File-managers/JFileProcessor.shtml https://github.com/stant/jfileprocessor

Will let you search for files with glob or regex, in subfolders to X or all depth, by name, size, date. You can save to a List window or file. Then you can run a groovy (think java) script to do whatever you want to the list of files; zip or tar them, modify the list strings like sed, delete, move, copy files, grep or ls -l them, whatever. In your case you can modify an existing groovy example to do something like:

```
    int numItems = defaultComboBoxModel.getSize();
    System.out.println( "defaultComboBoxModel.getSize() num of items =" + numItems + "=" );
    String str = "";
    for( int i = 0; i < numItems; i++ )
        {
        str = defaultComboBoxModel.getElementAt( i ).toString();
        System.out.println( "file of index =" + i + "   str =" + str + "=" );

            String cmd = "mv " + str + " " + i + ".jpg";  // or whatever
            def list = cmd.execute().text   // this stuff just captures output and write to a log file
            list.eachLine{
                outFile << it;
                }
            outFile << System.getProperty("line.separator") + "-------------------------------------" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        }
```

It will also let you massage your list like add to, delete from, subtract one list from another.